# Backend order where customer then makes payment

Tags: magento-1.8

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask this or if anyone can point me in the right direction.

I am looking for some kind of plugin that will allow me to create an order on the backend and then email the customer with a link to the new order where they can then go through the checkout process to make payment.

I have been looking for this for a while but either i don't quite know what ti would be called or the solutions are very costly and have many more features that i don't require.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Martin Hughes,

First of all,You `cannot  checkout without email Address`.

As  alternative solution, i can say that ,`Create order as Guest  from Backend and then register Customer from Manage Customer section`.

After that put `customer id to Sales Order table Like Sales_flat_order,  Sales_flat_order_grid Customer id field`.It may help  you

Also you cannot pay later after order place.It not possible;

Comment: Hi, i can make the order on the back end just fine but its the payment thing that is causing the issues. i want the customer to make payment through our payment gateway so it goes through all the security checks...is there a plugin that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Just like Third party redirecting payment, orders r created first and gateway callback updates the order status and creates the invoice. In your case it should be the later case.

Answer (score 0):

With default magento settings, you can add products on registered customer's cart from admin panel. However to let customer know you will need to email them manually or can write a module.

First you will need to register your customer in your site if they are not registered.
Then go to create order section on magento admin panel, and choose that customer. Then select products to the "Add product" section. And finally choose "Move to Shopping Cart" from "Action" field in same section (Order) then hit "Update Item and Quantity".
**See attached images.**[image] [image]

Then you will need to ask your customer to do the checkout. Item will be in their cart already.

Hope this helps.